# single producer single consumer queue with "blocking" pop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm looking for single producer single consumer queue with "blocking" pop.
Boost [spsc_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) almost fine except of one method:

```
bool pop(T & ret);
Pops one object from ringbuffer.
```

This method is "non-blocking", returns immediately if there are no data.
I want this method to "block" and wait until some data arrives.

What collections should I use?

**upd** At least could someone suggest any c++ queue with blocking pop?

Comment: See [`tbb:concurrent_bounded_queue`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm)

Comment: interesting. should I replace boost spsc_queue with intel version as well?

Comment: and what else do we have except intel's implementation?

Comment: there are very few *serious* concurrent c++ library. As stated in my answer, I would strongly consider wrapping an existing container.

Comment: as I understand `tbb:concurrent_bounded_queue` is multiple producers, multiple consumers. I need one producer one consumer queue, can this simplify things? Probably simpler implementation can be used?

Comment: how good this implementation? https://github.com/juanchopanza/cppblog/blob/master/Concurrency/Queue/Queue.h http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent queues rarely offer pop blocking interfaces: in many cases the user is expected to do the blocking logic, avoiding unnecessary overhead for the queue implementation.

That is, you can add a wrapper around your `queue::pop` to do something like :

```
bool blocking_pop(T & t) {
  while(!queue.empty())
    wait();
  return queue.pop(t);
}
```

**Intel TBB** has the [`tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm), which might also suits your needs.

Comment: why wrapping existent container is better than using tbb:concurrent_bounded_queue ?

Comment: @javapowered I don't claim it is better, but it might be less impacting to your current code base (no need to brin tbb in your project if you dont have it yet, not much code to modify)

Comment: bet performance of such queue is much worse comparing to intel's implementation?

Comment: @javapowered agree, but if the only thing you wrap is the blocking pop, then you are mostly comparing boost spsc vs tbb cbq, and I would benchmark to be sure ... but tbb queues are known to be *really* fast : )